# How to restore local GPO User Logon/Logoff script setting?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, scripting, deployment

I'm deploying several Windows 7 machines, and apply a GPOPack (exported through MSCM's LocalGPO utility) to set the Local GPO (no AD in there).

My issue is that logon & logoff scripts settings are not preserved through the LocalGPO tools export or GPOPack methods.
I'm talking about the `User Configuration/Windows Settings/Scripts (Logon/Logoff)/` settings in gpedit.msc

I can't find their "physical" representation either (registry or filesystem under `%windir%\system32\GroupPolicy\`).

During deployment, I make sure that the called scripts are copied under `%windir%\system32\GroupPolicy\User\Script\[Logon|Logoff]` before importing the GPOPack.

Is there a scripted/command line way to set these settings, or to import/export them from a Local GPO on a running system ?

Comment: You should consider doing whatever the logon script is doing via gp prefs.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts definitions for local group policy are stored in:

- `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\scripts.ini`
- `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\scripts.ini`

The file is hidden, so you may have to turn on hidden files to see it.